# Getting errorCode":"E0000005","errorSummary":"Invalid session" via google-apps-script

Tags: session, google-apps-script, cookies, postman, okta

I want to GET the user details based on email. So I am trying to use this Okta API https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#get-user-with-login . I am able to use it via Postman and curl. But via google-apps-script I get errorCode":"E0000005","errorSummary":"Invalid session". I am not sure on how I can clear the session or cookie in google-apps-script so that it starts working. I am certain that I am using the proper token and end point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Invalid session" error usually occurs when the API token you are using doesn't have sufficient permissions. Check to see if you are using the same API key/token in postman as in the script.

Comment: Turns out in google apps script the functions present in any of the files are global and they should have unique names. So i had a getToken() method for okta token and another getToken() method already existed in another file, which was returing some other JWT Token. So I am accepting this answer. Thanks